# Puppet Packages, Puppet Forge, and good Puppet code?

Tags: apache-2.2, puppet, libraries

Does anyone have a ranking system for the packages available from the [Forge at PuppetLabs](http://forge.puppetlabs.com)?

For example, there a half dozen Apache packages.  Given normal distribution, one will probably work, one will work a bit with different features, and the rest are unfinished little hacks.   Someone knows which one to use.

How would I find out?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there isn't an official ranking system for packages, but you can approach the community directly through IRC and the their Google Group and poll them on what works and what doesn't you can find the links to all the key resources here: http://www.puppetlabs.com/community/overview.

Many of the modules will require some degree of customisation and dependant upon your use case and methology it may define which module you use or perhaps cause you to refactor your puppet code in the long run.

Here's a really good slide from Puppet Camp Europe 2010 - http://www.lab42.it/presentations/puppetmodules/puppetmodules.html which may help you better choose and create your modules.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea. I agree there should be more "github-like" features that show you the project's activity, history, comments and ratings. However, with any project, the thing I would look at first is the amount of documentation. :)